# CSS selector for custom data-attribute?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, custom-data-attribute

Why my star is not appearing in YELLOW ? How to fix it ?

Here's the relevant code for the above issue.

**HTML**

```
<div class="tpl" data-favorite="1">
  <div>
    <span class="favorite">★</span>
    <span class="text">Italian Pizza: salmon, olives, onion, tomato, blue-cheese</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
[data-favorite=1] {
    background: #AAA;
    border-left: 3px solid green
}
.favorite {
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: 0 1 0 1em;
}
[data-favorite=1] .favorite {
    color:yellow;
}
[data-favorite=0] .favorite {
    color:#AAA;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L6pWS/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select elements by data attribute in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You'll want to use

```
[data-favorite="1"] {}
```

The difference being the quotes "" around the value.

Here's the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/Ext5N/)

Answer (score 12):

You need to use `"` around the attribute value

```
[data-favorite="1"] {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L6pWS/2/)

---

**Why is that so?**

CSS Specification - 6.3. Attribute selectors

> Attribute values must be CSS [identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)<sup>[1]</sup> or [strings](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings).
>   [[CSS21]](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#CSS21) The case-sensitivity of attribute names and values in
>   selectors depends on the document language.

Identifiers

> <sup>[1]</sup> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); *they cannot start with a digit*, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

---

So the issue is that the value of your attribute starts with a number, if you have something like this in your HTML *(You already do)*

```
<span data-favorite="0">Color Me red</span>
```

```
[data-favorite=0] { color: red;}
```

**WONT WORK**

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L6pWS/5/)

---

But, if you have something like

```
<span data-favorite="a0">Color Me red</span>

[data-favorite=a0] { color: red;}
```

**WILL WORK** *(Even without quotes)* because the value of your attribute starts with an alphabet <sup>[1]</sup>.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L6pWS/4/)