# how to css for data attribute

Tags: html, css

i want to css for my data attribute. i know how to do before and after but it is not for before and after. i will be my image caption i want to change that color, font size, font family etc..

```
<a href="products/Comfo-Back-Adirondack-Chair.jpg" class="ilightbox" data-caption="Adirondack Chair, PATC2400, Size : 32” W x 36” D x 40” H"><img src="products/th/Comfo-Back-Adirondack-Chair.jpg" /></a>
```

see the **data-caption** this is one value not fix . if fix then i can but it not fix but how can do. have any way ?

Comment: Strangely, for all its sheer popularity, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css) does not come up in the list of suggestions (I just checked myself). I wonder why.

Comment: If you're wanting to apply styles to the value of `"Adirondack Chair, ..."`, you'll need to explain how it's being rendered. The attribute alone doesn't do that; it's just text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following to select by attribute:

```
[data-caption] {
  /* rules */
}
```

If you want to only select elements where the attribute has a given value:

```
[data-caption="this is the value"] {
  /* rules */
}
```

Read more about the different kinds of attribute selectors at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)