# Select custom attribute to set style

Tags: jquery, html, css

Select  `data-ctrtid` custom attribute to set style

HTML snip

```
<div class="expandListHeaderRow" data-ctryid="28fa1d89-eabe-44b5-b761-897b7835d7ab">South Africa</div>
```

This is dynamically created code and I capture the id correctly like this.

```
$('.expandListDetail').on('click', '.expandListHeader', function(){
   var argument = $(this).closest('.expandListHeader').find('div').data('ctryid');
   .
   .
}
```

But after I refresh the list, I want to expand the list to the place where it was before. (this is a dynamic multi expandable/Collapsible list)

`data('ctryid').css('display': 'block')` or somthing like this.

But how do you search for the specific **ID** of the custom attribute to target the element for CSS change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5324433/3691686

Comment: @marcelo2605 No not exactly. this is setting the style for a before hand ( i think). I have atleast 20 `data-ctryId`s so will need to target only the specific one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have the id, and you need to find the element.  If so, this will work:

```
$('[data-ctryid="' + capturedId + '"]')
```

See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: I though that at first, but *they already have that element* as they found it and retrieved the `data('ctryid')` from it.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes, perhaps you are right.  It just seemed like his jQuery knowledge extended beyond the basic concept of selecting an element by id.  Maybe the OP will clarify.

Comment: I hope they clarify. The question is ambiguous at best. While true, your example is pointless though, as they *already have* the element that has that attribute so a search returns the same element they already have.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for an id by string variable value, convert it to a jQuery ID selector (i.e. prefix with `#`):

```
$('#' + data('ctryid'))
```

so your example becomes:

```
$('#' + data('ctryid')).css('display': 'block')
```

This of course assumes you have elements like this somewhere in the page:

```
<div id="28fa1d89-eabe-44b5-b761-897b7835d7ab">
```