# How To Style A Class Based On Unique ID?

Tags: html, css, field, styling

I'm working in a Salesforce APP called Skuid. I can only style by CSS / Javascript and I don't have access to the HTML.

Anyway I'm designing a contact form and this is how the individual fields are styled:

```
<div class="nx-field nx-modified required" data-uid="20"><textarea></textarea></div>
```

They each have a unique "data-uid" number.

How can I target data-uid="20" in CSS? Any way to do that? I searched around and can't find anything.

Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [CSS attribute selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```css
div[data-uid="20"] {
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="nx-field nx-modified required" data-uid="20">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
<div class="nx-field nx-modified required" data-uid="21">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thanks here. but f it. THANKS! I'm so happy to have this issue solved!!