# How to target itemid="" in CSS

Tags: html, css

Example HTML:

```
<div itemid="MenuContainer" id="MenuContainer" class="MenuContainer">
```

Example CSS:

```
#MenuContainer {

   /* Styles */

}
```

How can I use CSS to target `ItemID` instead of the regular `ID`?

Comment: Why do you need to, and why are you making up attributes instead of using HTML5 custom data attributes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select elements by data attribute in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css)

Comment: knitevision = multiple accounts.  check serial down voting on her rep.  just ignore it.  there are a lot of people like that on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of #MenuContainer, use this.

`[itemid="MenuContainer"] { /*CSS STYLES*/ }`

This will use data attribute (itemid) and the value (MenuContainer) from the HTML tag.

see this http://jsfiddle.net/442hdc0p/

Comment: Yes I agree. How did you get two down votes? You answered with exactly what I needed. Thank you. When it lets me you get the green check.

Comment: Thank you Dustin, I believe it was knitevision.  I checked her reputation and she has lost reputation on serial downvoting in the past.  Guessing multiple accounts.  She wasnt happy that aparently this question is similar to others.

Answer (score -1):

You should not even try to do that.
Instead, use unique class for this element.
In your example you could add `class="MenuContainer extraClass"` and then in CSS use `.extraClass { color: #FFF; }` or whatever to define, what you need.

Comment: Thank you also. You just taught me something new that will be helpful in the future thanks.