# Data attributes with css selectors

Tags: css, attributes

I am trying to remove a div targeting it with a data selector.

css

```
[data-id="b5c3cde7-8aa1"]  {
    display:none;
}
```

does not work. Is is possible?

Comment: Simply, you forgot to create element with `data-id` attribute. https://jsfiddle.net/nyqxkmpz/

Comment: It works http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJPYKJ

Comment: Yes of course it works:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you have to add this attribute to the div then hide it:

```css
[data-id="b5c3cde7-8aa1"]  {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div data-id="b5c3cde7-8aa1">hide me</div>
```