# Html <object data> styling

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-domain

```
<div> 
    <object type="text/html" id="tsete" data="http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp" width="100%" height:"800px"; style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 900px;"></object>
</div>
```

I created this `object` inside of a `div`. It's showing the website that is referenced in the `data` attribute. I'm showing Google as an example.

Is there anyway to style the `div` elements within that `object data`? Styling the google divs while on my website? Like changing shape or hiding them?

My logic was, since the content is already on my page when the object retrieves the data from the other website, i could easily style it, at the end of the body since there were already divs implemented from the other website

**EDIT**

Changed the reference of the `<object data="">`, soo you guys can try it

Comment: No. You cannot affect cross domain content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select elements by data attribute in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css)

Comment: @Germano Plebani: Not remotely the same thing.