# Checking if data attribute is set at parent div css / less and using it for the child divs as well

Tags: css, html

I have `div` tag for which a `data-type` attribute is associated. I want to apply different styles depending on data-type is set or no.

```
<div data-type="type1">Hello, World!</div>
```

Can I check if this attribute `data-type` is set or no in css/less ? This question is solved with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css).

---

But, if I apply this `data-type` attribute only to the parent `div`, can I use this attribute for all the child `div` tags as well. 
For instance,

```
<div data-type=`type1`>
  <div id="newDiv"> </div>
</div>
```

In my CSS, I want to apply different styles for `#newDiv` depending on whatever type (`data-type`) is set to its parent. I don't want to specify the `data-type` attribute to the child `div` as well. How do we do this in CSS ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select elements by data attribute in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:not([data-type])` to select any element that does not have the attribute `data-type` set regardless of the values used.

Basic working example:

```css
div:not([data-type]) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-type="type1">Hello, World!</div>

<div>Hello, World!</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the opposite and use `[data-type]` to select anything with the `data-type` attribute set regardless of the value

Working example:

```css
div[data-type] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-type="type1">Hello, World!</div>

<div>Hello, World!</div>
```

---

If you want to target a child div whose parent div has the `data-type` attribute set the you can use something like this:

```css
div[data-type]>h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-type="type1">Hello, World!
  <h1> How are you?!</h1>
</div>

<hr>

<div>Hello, World!
  <h1> How are you?!</h1>
</div>
```

This also can be reveresed based on your selector preference to target the child elements of parent elements which do not have the `data-type` attribute set.

```css
div:not([data-type])>h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-type="type1">Hello, World!
  <h1> How are you?!</h1>
</div>

<hr>

<div>Hello, World!
  <h1> How are you?!</h1>
</div>
```

---

If you have more complex structures you can make use of the wildcard `*` selector to build selectors that match very broad patterns. The letters represent the depth of the tree on which the element resides with `aaa` being a direct child and `bbb` being a grandchild...etc

Basic Example:

```css
[data-type] * h1,
[data-type] h1 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-type="type1">
  <h1> aaa</h1>
</div>

<hr>

<div>
  <h1> aaa</h1>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="test" data-type="type1">
  <div>
    <h1> bbb</h1>
    <div>
      <h1> ccc</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="wow"> aaa</h1>
  <div>
    <h1 class="wow"> bbb</h1>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div id="test">
  <h1 class="wow"> aaa</h1>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h1> ddd</h1>
    </div>
    <h1 class="wow"> ccc</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @I haz kode, The 3 and 4 snippets mentioned work only for immediate children. The immediate parent should have the data-* attribute set, otherwise style won't get applied. In my scenario multiple nesting of divs is there and only the top parent, I have the data-* attribute set.

Comment: @I haz kode, I have edited your answer to add snippet 5, where its actually failing. Is there any way to handle this scenario in css ?

Comment: Let me take a quick look, I'll post as soon as I have anything @Chaitanya

Comment: @Chaitanya See if the latest update addresses the issue. Let me know if it does not.

Comment: @I haz kode, definitely, here in the snippet you have attached, the issue is resolved. But, in the scenario, I am dealing with its not working. Moreover, my UI is being created dynamically, I m thinking if that might be causing the issue.

Comment: @I haz kode, Hey actually, I was stuck in some silly issue. It works now. Thanks a lot :).

Comment: @Chaitanya No worries, glad you sorted it out and happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you find a pattern in your `data-type` value, yes, you can:

```
/* 1. Attribute value starts with "type" */
div[data-type^="type"] {
    /* Styles */
}

/* 2. Attribute value contains "type" */
div[data-type*="type"] {
    /* Styles */
}
```

1. Works for: **type1**, **typex**, **typeaskdasd**, etc...
2. Works for: *abc**type**xyz*, ***type***xyz, etc...