# Is there an alternative version of the "contain: content;" CSS property?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for an alt of `contain: content;` CSS property for old browsers compatibility.
Is there any? Or at the least is there a CSS trick for that?

Comment: Please explain your problem by giving real example what do you want to achieve? This question doesn't explain everything.

Comment: This new css rule can make any element contain its content so it will not gonna displayed outside its border, for example if u applied  a blur filter on it, it will not gonna affect the outside at all.

Comment: The problem is I can't use it because not all browser support it

Comment: Alternative is to use data attributes in your html and apply css to data attributes.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're using `contain: content` for, but in some situations you can substitute:

```
overflow: hidden
```

and you will be okay.

This is because `contain: content` is a shorthand for `contain: layout paint`.

It is `contain: paint` which (visually, at least) produces an outcome which greatly resembles `overflow: hidden`.

**Working Example:**

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 12px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.outer p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 0;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.outer-3 {
  contain: content;
}

.outer-4 {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}

.inner-2,
.inner-3,
.inner-4 {
  margin-top: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer outer-1">
<p>1</p>
<div class="inner outer-1"></div>
</div>

<div class="outer outer-2">
<p>2</p>
<div class="inner inner-2"></div>
</div>

<div class="outer outer-3">
<p>3</p>
<div class="inner inner-3"></div>
</div>

<div class="outer outer-4">
<p>4</p>
<div class="inner inner-4"></div>
</div>
```

In the example above:

1. **Outer** has no special rules and **Inner** has no `margin-top`
2. **Outer** has no special rules and **Inner** has a `margin-top` of `75px`
3. **Outer** has `contain: content` and **Inner** has a `margin-top` of `75px`
4. **Outer** has `overflow: hidden` and **Inner** has a `margin-top` of `75px`

---

**Further Reading:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/contain
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Containment
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/12/browsers-containment-css-contain-property/

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is to use data attributes in your html and apply css to data attributes.
Refer this answer:
[Select elements by data attribute in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css)