# Possible to target an element by its value in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css

Here's what  I have in my JS:

```
if ($('#submit').attr('value') == 'Save Changes'){
    $('#submit').hide();
};
```

Is there a way to target an element by its Value in CSS, and then hide it if its value == something?

If not- Is there a way to make this code faster? I can see the Hide happening when I load the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select elements by data attribute in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-data-attribute-in-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the flash of the item before hiding - the best way is to flip the logic - start with it hidden and then show it if needed

```
// css
#submit {display: none};

// js
if ($('#submit').attr('value') !== 'Save Changes'){
    $('#submit').show();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use attribute selector and change the logic to prevent flashing:

```css
#submit {
  display: none;
}

#submit:not([value="Save Changes"]) {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Looking at your example, I made a discovery for myself :) nice