# how to hide a div if another div has a special attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure, what I want to achieve is that if the point class has the "black" attribute, the button does not appear. Someone who can help me please

```
     <div class="container" > 

         <div class="card" > 
           <div class="button" > button </div>
            <div class="colors" > 
             <div value="black" class="point"> </div>
             <div value="white" class="point"> </div>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div> 


        if ($('.point').attr("value") == "black") {
              $(".button").hide();
         }
```

Comment: You can search for any attribute with a query selector. In your case `.button[value="black"]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select elements by attribute in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-attribute-in-css)

Comment: forget to say that there are several "container" divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select everything with the class `point` which has a specific attribute (in this case `value="black"`). Then find the sibling of the parent div with the class `.button` and hide it. No need for the `if` statement.

```
$('.point[value="black"]').parent().siblings(".button").hide();
```

Comment: And if for some strange reason I have to put the "div.point" 7 div inside, how do I do it?

Comment: *"put the "div.point" 7 div"* - what's the "div.point 7 div"?

Comment: with "parents" thanks for the great response and taking the time to help.