# How do i access HTML text elements using data-* attributes if my code does not have attribute id?

Tags: javascript

I know how to access HTML elements using:

```
document.getElementById(element_ID);
```

but what if there's no ID attributes?

Example:

```
<ul data-vehicle="Car">
    <li data-model="Sedan">2.5HP</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) + [Select elements by attribute in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-attribute-in-css)

Comment: I agree with @DBS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select elements by attribute in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324415/select-elements-by-attribute-in-css)

Comment: there should be a `''` while referring to an Id `document.getElementById('element_ID');` who has edited the question?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.querySelector("[data-model='Sedan']")` but keep in mind that `querySelector` is not supported on IE7.

Comment: If anyone is still having to maintain IE7 in 2022 they have my sincerest condolences.

Comment: @DBS I concur :-)

Comment: I do sadly. Yet there is a polyfill for it.